# Конструкция «e => e» в LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

```
 Dictionary<int, int> TestDictionary;   
 TestDictionary = a.ToDictionary(e => e.a, e => e.b);
```

В этом коде `e` — класс, внутри которого объявлены внутренние поля `a` b `b` типа `int`.

Вопрос: что означает конструкция типа `e => e.a`? Думал про лямбду, но мне кажется, не оно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Думал про лямбду, но мне кажется не оно

e => e.a  - это действительно лямбда-функция.  В вашем случае - это некая функция, которая принимает экземпляр некоего класса, и возвращает int. В итоге вы получаете Dictionary<int, int>, в котором ключами являются поля a, а значениями - поля b из некоего a, который вы в этот самый Dictionary преобразуете, и который, по всей вероятности представляет собой некий IEnumerable<что-то там>

Comment: (уголок зануды) в зависимости от реальной сигнатуры метода `ToDictionary`, `e => e.a` может оказаться и `Expression<Func<X, Y>>` (так происходит, например, в LINQ-to-SQL).

Comment: спасибо за занудство - признаюсь, я об этом забыл